# Interactive lambda only calls 1 of several functions called in body

Tags: key-bindings, evil, term, multi-term

In term-mode I've configured the keybindings for `term-line-mode` and `term-char-mode` as follows:

```el
(setq term-bind-key-alist
      (list (cons "C-c C-j" '(lambda () (interactive)
                               (term-line-mode)
                               (evil-normal-state)))
            (cons "C-c C-k" '(lambda () (interactive)
                               (term-char-mode)
                               (evil-emacs-state)
                               (end-of-buffer)))
```

This gives the expected behavior when I type "C-c C-j" but only `term-char-mode` seems to be called when I type "C-c C-k". All of them are called if I type "C-c C-k" for a 2nd time. How can I get them to work on the first key press?

---

Edit 1

Here's the full configuration for term. Also, I mistakenly thought that this is a variable for term-mode, when it's actually a variable defined in **multi-term**. However, if I place this in the multi-term configuration it produces the same behavior

```el
(use-package term
  :after helm
  :config
  (defun expose-global-binding-in-term (binding)
    (define-key term-raw-map binding
      (lookup-key (current-global-map) binding)))
  (expose-global-binding-in-term (kbd "C-x"))
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
  (setq term-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)
  (setq term-scroll-show-maximum-output t))

(use-package multi-term
  :bind (("<C-next>" . multi-term-next)
         ("<C-prior>" . multi-term-prev)
         ("<f1>" . multi-term))
  :config
  (require 'multi-term-ext)
  (setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
  (setq term-bind-key-alist
        (list (cons "C-c C-c" 'term-interrupt-subjob)
              (cons "C-z" 'term-stop-subjob)
              (cons "C-l" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "C-r" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "C-s" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "M-f" 'term-send-forward-word)
              (cons "M-b" 'term-send-backward-word)
              (cons "C-c C-j" '(lambda () (interactive)
                                 (term-line-mode)
                                 (evil-normal-state)))
              (cons "C-c C-k" '(lambda () (interactive)
                                 (evil-emacs-state)
                                 (term-char-mode)
                                 (end-of-buffer)))
              (cons "M-DEL" 'term-send-backward-kill-word)
              (cons "M-d" 'term-send-forward-kill-word)
              (cons "<C-left>" 'term-send-backward-word)
              (cons "<C-right>" 'term-send-forward-word)
              (cons "C-y" 'term-paste))))
```

---

Edit 2

I've modified the multi-term configuration so that these keybindings are outside of `term-bind-key-alist` but I'm still getting the same behavior.

```el
(use-package multi-term
  :bind (("<C-next>" . multi-term-next)
         ("<C-prior>" . multi-term-prev)
         ("<f1>" . multi-term)
         ("C-c C-j" . (lambda () (interactive)
                        (term-line-mode)
                        (evil-normal-state)))
         ("C-c C-k" . (lambda () (interactive)
                        (evil-emacs-state)
                        (term-char-mode)
                        (end-of-buffer))))
  :config
  (require 'multi-term-ext)
  (setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
  (setq term-bind-key-alist
    (list (cons "C-c C-c" 'term-interrupt-subjob)
          (cons "C-z" 'term-stop-subjob)
          (cons "C-l" 'term-send-raw)
          (cons "C-r" 'term-send-raw)
          (cons "C-s" 'term-send-raw)
          (cons "M-f" 'term-send-forward-word)
          (cons "M-b" 'term-send-backward-word)
          (cons "M-DEL" 'term-send-backward-kill-word)
          (cons "M-d" 'term-send-forward-kill-word)
          (cons "<C-left>" 'term-send-backward-word)
          (cons "<C-right>" 'term-send-forward-word)
          (cons "C-y" 'term-paste))))
```

---

Edit 3

The version below now works. The trick, as pointed out by Phil in his answer, is that
`term-bind-key-alist` doesn't bind keys for `term-mode-map` (used by `term-line-mode`). I believe it only
binds keys for `term-raw-map`, or some combination of that and `term-raw-escape-map`. The reason that
`term-char-mode` was still called (and the other two functions weren't) when using "C-c C-k" in term-line-mode was that it's the default
keybinding in `term-line-mode`.

```el
(use-package term
  :after (helm evil)
  :bind (:map term-mode-map
              ("C-c C-k" . (lambda () (interactive)
                             (evil-emacs-state)
                             (term-char-mode)
                             (goto-char (point-max)))))
  :config
  (defun expose-global-binding-in-term (binding)
    (define-key term-raw-map binding
      (lookup-key (current-global-map) binding)))
  (expose-global-binding-in-term (kbd "C-x"))
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)
  (setq term-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)
  (setq term-scroll-show-maximum-output t))

(use-package multi-term
  :bind (("<C-next>" . multi-term-next)
         ("<C-prior>" . multi-term-prev)
         ("<f1>" . multi-term))
  :config
  (require 'multi-term-ext)
  (setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
  (setq term-bind-key-alist
        (list (cons "C-c C-c" 'term-interrupt-subjob)
              (cons "C-z" 'term-stop-subjob)
              (cons "C-l" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "C-r" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "C-s" 'term-send-raw)
              (cons "M-f" 'term-send-forward-word)
              (cons "M-b" 'term-send-backward-word)
              ;; I've defined "C-c C-k" in term's configuration since it must be defined in
              ;; term-mode-map.  It could be placed here as a define-key in config, but this way we
              ;; get to keep use-package's typical syntax.
              (cons "C-c C-j" '(lambda () (interactive)
                                 (term-line-mode)
                                 (evil-normal-state)))
              (cons "M-DEL" 'term-send-backward-kill-word)
              (cons "M-d" 'term-send-forward-kill-word)
              (cons "<C-left>" 'term-send-backward-word)
              (cons "<C-right>" 'term-send-forward-word)
              (cons "C-y" 'term-paste))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs 26.1 does not define `term-bind-key-alist`.  If you don't show us what you're doing with that, we can't see what the problem is.

That said, it sounds like you're only binding keys in `term-raw-map`, and not in `term-mode-map`.

n.b. For clarity, I do not believe "lambda only calls 1 of several functions called in body" is something which is happening.  I think you'll find that your custom commands are not being called *at all* when you are in line mode (because the keys sequence in question is not bound to your custom command in that scenario).

---

Try this.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "term"
  (require 'evil)

  (defun my-term-line-mode ()
    "Switch to `term-line-mode' and enable `evil-normal-state'."
    (interactive)
    (term-line-mode)
    (evil-normal-state))

  (defun my-term-char-mode ()
    "Switch to `term-char-mode' and enable `evil-emacs-state'."
    (interactive)
    (term-char-mode)
    (evil-emacs-state))

  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-j") 'my-term-line-mode)
  (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'my-term-char-mode)
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map (kbd "C-j") 'my-term-line-mode)
  (define-key term-raw-escape-map (kbd "C-k") 'my-term-char-mode))
```

Comment: I've edited the original post to add more context. Also please see my note about this actually being a variable for multi-term. My mistake for incorrectly assuming this  was part of term mode.

Comment: In that case it sounds like `multi-term` is using it to bind keys in `term-raw-map`, and not in `term-mode-map`.  I suggest that you ignore this variable, and just bind the keys you want in the keymaps you need using the standard `define-key` method.

Comment: i.e. I suspect the answer to your question is simply that `term-bind-key-alist` doesn't actually do what you thought it did.

Comment: I pulled these keybindings out of `term-bind-key-alist` and edited the question to reflect that. Unfortunately the behavior seems to be identical.

Comment: I've no idea what `use-package` does with that new config, but it will again surely only bind the keys in (at most) *one* of the two keymaps you're interested in.  You need to bind these particular key sequences in *both* `term-mode-map` and `term-raw-map`, because they need to work in *both* line mode and char mode.

Comment: In fact I was wrong -- in char mode, if overriding sequences starting with the escape key `C-c`, one actually uses `term-raw-escape-map`.  I've added code to the answer.

Comment: Ok the final version in my edits now works. I wasn't able to get `term-raw-escape-map` to work for some reason.. In any event you're right that I was failing to bind anything in `term-mode-map`.

Comment: If you run `emacs -Q` and evaluate the code I suggested (and `M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs.d/elpa/evil*/evil-autoloads.el`), then it should be working.